# What is the purpose of using node_submit() before node_save()?

Tags: nodes

I am creating a node programmatically , In the code given in the link 
http://timonweb.com/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7
after creating a node,
the code goes as follows :

```
 $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
    node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`node_submit()` is a small helper function that makes sure the uid/author and creation date is set. Its main purpose is to map ->name to uid and ->date to created. Those two are used in the node edit/create form.

So if you set these two properties yourself anyway (and the validated flag but I haven't found anything that cares about it, likely some sort of left-over from earlier code), there is no need to call it.

Answer (score 2):

you should also use node_object_prepare($node) which helps in doing the following: Provides the default values for the status, promote, sticky, and revision flags. These values are type specific if $node->type is defined, and can be modified as required.

Answer (score 0):

Why node_submit() is overriding the uid based on $node->name ($form_state['values']['name']) ?

```
if ($account = user_load_by_name($node->name)) {
  $node->uid = $account->uid;
}
```